# Strange behavior of the vertical padding

Tags: html, css, padding

The problem is the vertical padding on the psd layout 30px and 30px, but in practice, setting this size in the css code in the browser show padding 35px and 35px.
Reset margin and padding for everything that only it is possible, there is no result.

Help please to understand, maybe somewhere something overlooked.

**screenshot** https://yadi.sk/d/LsDSh_UZTDZDW

**html**

```
  <header class="header">
    <div class="container">
       <nav class="header-menu">
         <ul>
       <li><a href="#">Главная</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Информация</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Новости</a></li>
         </ul>
       </nav>
    </div>
  </header>
```

**css**

```
body {
font-size: 16px;
width: 100%;
}
.container {
margin: 0 auto;
width: 940px;
}
/* Header */
.header {
background: #000000;
width: 100%;
border-top: 1px solid #242424;
}
/* Header --> menu */
.header-menu li {
display: inline-block;
}
.header-menu a {
color: #fff;
display: inline-block;
padding-top: 30px;
padding-bottom: 31px;
padding-left: 22px;
padding-right: 22px;
margin-right: -0.2em;
text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`ul` element gives you default `padding-left` and  `margin-top` and `body` gives `margin` :

```
nav.header-menu ul { padding:0; margin:0; }
body {margin : 0}
```

#### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y7WYF/7/)

Comment: @gershmit : from the `body` element. Updated.

Comment: oh! I find problem, need to add .header-menu li { line-height: 1em; }. That's work!

Comment: @gershmit : However I don't see `padding:10px` there. But glad to help you, anyway.

Comment: I screenshot result JSFiddle and measure in graphics editor and see `padding:10px`

Comment: @gershmit : I think I understand what was causing this issue.As you use inline-block layout spaces after each li are are displayed as spacing between the blocks.I updated my fiddle with possible html workaround.(look at the html structure, no spacing between li).By the way,`header`

Comment: @gershmit : Have you succeeded?